# Boost spirit grammar to skip php comments. Is this working code written with the current recommended boost parser?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've done a function that strips all comments and a few other elements from php code. It's working fine, but, as I do not deeply undertand the code, I have some doubts:

- Am I using the latest technology to parse a grammar in boost? A few years ago I used only `Spirit` but I didn't use `qi`.
- Is this the right approach with spirit?
- What is the reason for putting the grammar inside a block of code?

  ```
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    using namespace std;

    string non_comments_php_code(const string &contents)
    {
        string non_comments_code;
        using Iterator = string::const_iterator;
        Iterator begin = contents.cbegin(), end = contents.cend();

        using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;
        auto identifier = qi::standard_wide::char_;
        Skipper block_comment, single_line_comment, skipper,
            php_tag, php_comment, php_namespace, php_use;
        {
            using namespace qi;
            single_line_comment = "//" >> *(standard_wide::char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
            block_comment       = ("/*" >> *(block_comment | standard_wide::char_ - "*/")) > ("*/"|eoi);
            php_tag             = lit("<?php") | lit("?>");
            php_comment         = '#' >> *(standard_wide::char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
            php_namespace       = lit("namespace ") >> *(standard_wide::char_ - (eol|';')) >> (eol|';');
            php_use             = lit("use ") >> *(standard_wide::char_ - (eol|';')) >> (eol|';');
            skipper             = space | single_line_comment | block_comment | php_tag | php_namespace | php_use | php_comment;
        }
        bool ok = phrase_parse(begin, end, skipper, skipper);
        if ( begin != end) {
            while( begin != end && *begin != '\n') {
                non_comments_code += *begin++;
            }
        }
        return non_comments_code;
   }
  ```

**EDIT:**
The goal of the function is to return any code in the php file that is neither a comment nor a (use|namespace) statement nor the tags `<?php` .. `?>`

I am using templates to autogenerate php code, and once the code is created, I can add custom code. Previous to calling this function I manage to delete all the automatic code that was generated, and then this function tells me if I have added any custom code to the php file.

Thas is why I say it is working, as I dont mind the code, I just want to know if there is any custom code at all.

**EDIT 2:**

Example of input string:

```
<?php

namespace tests;
use codeception/tests;

/* This unit test tests something */

class Tester {

    /// @group debug
    public function testsFeature(/*AcceptanceTester*/ $I) {
        $I->assertTrue($this->testsAll());
    }
}
?>
```

And the required output:

```
classTester{publicfunctiontestsFeature($I){$I->assertTrue($this->testsAll());}}
```

In fact, the result has no any useful use, I just need to know if it is empty.

There are other approaches to solve the whole problem, like regenerating the template in a temp file and diff'ing it to get the addition changes, but that 1) would be far more expensive, 2) I really want to learn to use boost grammar parsers.

Comment: How does it "work fine". It also strips use/namespace clauses and `<?php ... ?>` blocks. That seems to conflict with the stated goal. Consider showing input/output example and expectations. Regardless, there is no parser, not output. Really it cannot "work" under any reasonable definition of work as shown. There's lot's of pretty careful correct details about the rules, so it's not all bad.

Comment: I aplogize. I didn't mention in the heading that the function was stripping <?php and namespaces, but I did in the body of the question. My question was about the correctness of the function rather than if it worked or not, as I am using it an it really works :)

Comment: But doesn't `<?php`...`?>` mark the CODE? So you want to keep **only** what's inside them? Just swallowing them is going to return /everything/ outside the code blocks as well

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify the goal

Comment: The clarification makes some sense now. I guess you could also just compare the strings, but could be slightly more intelligent. I'd personally keep the `using`, `namespace` and `<?php` directives because they too alter meaning.

Comment: I have edited againg my question, as I have realized that the output string is meaningless and that is making the whole goal difficult to understand. I only need to know if the result string is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see, the whole thing was a bit inside-out. You are "parsing" the stuff that you want to "skip" and "skipping" the stuff you need "outside the parser".

It seems a lot more straightforward to have a parser and skipper in their designated roles. Let's create a `StripCommentsParser`:

```
using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
struct StripCommentParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()> {
```

This declares the output `std::string` which we will use to collect the *desired* output. I'd put all the bits together like so:

```
struct StripCommentParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()> {
    StripCommentParser() : StripCommentParser::base_type(start) {

        using namespace qi;
        single_line_comment = "//" >> *(qi::char_ - eol) >> (eol | eoi);
        block_comment       = ("/*" >> *(block_comment | qi::char_ - "*/")) > ("*/" | eoi);
        php_tag             = lit("<?php") | lit("?>");
        php_comment         = '#' >> *(qi::char_ - eol) >> (eol | eoi);
        php_namespace       = lit("namespace ") >> *(qi::char_ - (eol | ';')) >> (eol | ';');
        php_use             = lit("use ") >> *(qi::char_ - (eol | ';')) >> (eol | ';');

        start = qi::skip(space | single_line_comment | block_comment | php_tag | php_namespace | php_use | php_comment)[*char_];
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator> block_comment, single_line_comment, php_tag, php_comment, php_namespace, php_use;
};

std::string non_comments_php_code(std::string const& contents) {
    std::string non_comments_code;
    parse(begin(contents), end(contents), StripCommentParser{}, non_comments_code);
    return non_comments_code;
}
```

Notes:

- no `phrase_parse` (as you should definitely not be able to change the skipper)
- rules combined into a grammar struct for encapsulation and re-use. Just slam `static` onto the parser and you insta-optimized your code:

  std::string non_comments_php_code(std::string const& contents) {
  std::string non_comments_code;
  static const StripCommentParser scp;
  parse(begin(contents), end(contents), scp, non_comments_code);
  return non_comments_code;
  }

#### Observations

- What's good

  I like how your code pays attention to when the rules should match at `qi::eoi`. This is oft neglected, and it shows you understand PEG grammar productions well.
- What's bad

  As I commented [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546078/boost-spirit-grammar-to-skip-php-comments-is-this-working-code-written-with-the#comment134963437_76546078) there are a lot of other things weird about this code:

  - you're also skipping `qi::space`?! That seems very unhelpful if the output should be useful for anything (other than counting code size ignoring **significant** whitespace?)
  - you're inside-out parse driver had **extra** logic to randomly also skip '\n'. That's odd, because

    ```
    (a) you had an entire parser to skip things already
    (b) that parser rule (`skipper`) includes `qi::space`, which includes `'\n'`
    ```
  - You're randomly using `standard_wide`. This is a bad idea because your input AND output are not wide-character. Also, I expect PHP is UTF8 by definition/convention.
  - Your patterns arbitrarily assume certain space use. E.g. `"namespace\t"` will not be matched

  If you care to explain what the *real goal* of the code is, I can tell you what I'd write.

#### Questions

> **Q.** Am I using the latest technology to parse a grammar in boost? A few years ago I used only Spirit but I didn't use qi.

That's interesting. "Years ago" is when I'd use Qi. Nowadays I still recommend Qi, but you have the option of using C++14 Spirit X3 (going C++17 now).

If all you're doing is squeezing ignorable input then I'd say X3 is a better choice. However there are areas where I think X3 isn't as mature (e.g. attribute propagation/handling).

> **Q.** Is this the right approach with spirit?

Yes and no. Yes in the sense that you create rules. No in the sense that you used the skipper as the grammar (and skipper too). And wrote your own parser around the skipper. I think the above example is what you want

> **Q.** What is the reason for putting the grammar inside a block of code?

Scope. That's what blocks do. In this case it limits the scope of all the detail rules, as well as the [`using namespace` directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives). The struct has the same goal but packaging it up in a reusable instance.

Comment: Here's (untested, because we don't have input/expected output) an X3 version that also fixes some of the remaining issues: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8caf12015b14809

Comment: the private part of `struct StripCommentParser` is duplicated by mistake, I guess

Comment: After coding your example, I'm getting this error: `/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/char_encoding/standard.hpp:122: static bool boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard::isspace(int): Assertion strict_ischar(ch) failed.
`.  All my input files are in UTF8 encoding

Comment: re "duplicated" - yes that was a copy paste error.

Comment: Which example are you referring to? I assume the Qi one, and yes, if you require UTF8 consider coding for it. How you do so depends what you require/have. So again, do you have samples?

Comment: I have edited again my question to clarify it more.